# Emacs auto-complete broke after update: required 'popup' feature not provided

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, popup, emacs24

After updating outdated packages, `auto-complete` (and its dependencies like `ac-slime`) broke with the error "Required feature 'popup' is not provided". Inspection of the `elpa` directory revealed that `popup` is there. Recompilation of everything in `elpa` directory with `byte-recompile-directory` did not solve the problem (both `popup.el` and `popup.elc` are present but `auto-complete` still fails).

PS. Further inspection revealed that some other packages are failing because `xml-prc` is absent, but Emacs shows that it is installed and it is indeed is present in `elpa` directory.

What are my steps to make Emacs work again?

Comment: `provide` statement of popup.el is [here](https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el/blob/master/popup.el#L1426). So I wonder why you get such error.

Comment: I am recalling now, in the past when packages update something might break, but usually it all can be sorted by recompiling everything. This time it didn't help. So, I sorted it by deleting `elpa` directory and reinstalling all the packages (in my `.emacs` I have the list of packages that needs to be installed if missing, so it was the matter of restarting Emacs). But this is rather a radical measure, I was wondering if there was a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no other answers yet (I hope there will be a real one!), here is what have worked in meantime:

Basically, during the package update something has gone wrong -- don't know what exactly. Usually, `byte-recompile-directory` on `elpa` directory helps to sort out the issue: it recompiles all the package files and after restart Emacs is usually can load them without problems. This time, however, it didn't help. So I used a more drastic measure: I deleted `elpa` directory form `~/.emacs.d` (or actually I moved it away), and restarted Emacs.

My `.emacs` file contains the list of packages that need to be installed if missing, so all the package re-installation happened automatically, I just needed to wait (circa 30 min) for Emacs to start.

(This is a well known trick, but if you interested, here is the source [on github](https://github.com/mobius-eng/.emacs.d/blob/master/alexey/general.el#L21))

But this solution is not ideal, I was hoping for something cleaner.